# How to make this AR (Augmented Reality) optics system work?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

This is what I have:
[image]

but it turns out that the image is too close to the eyes (duh :D) and it hurts trying to focus on it. Usually, VR and AR headsets use some type of lens system. My only idea right now would be to put a convex lens between the eyes and reflective glass (what VR does) but that would make the outside world very blurry. I've been going around and asking everyone but I can't seem to find a solution. For the world behind to not be blurry, the lenses have to be between the display and the reflective glass. I'm not sure what to do.

My goal is for it to be compact, projected image not distorted, the world behind not blurry and the whole thing to be cheap. <-- this is what my goal is but I've been trying to bring it to life without success for the last two days.

If there's no way to make it (even though there's always a way) I'm ready to put a convex lens between the eyes and reflective surface and that would make the world behind blurry, but... it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Put the lens between the projector and the beam splitter.

By the way, please please please do not use acronyms in subject lines without defining them unless you are sure that everyone will know what they mean.  For example "QM" for quantum mechanics is probably ok.  "SR" for Special Theory or Relativity is dicey, so define it to be sure.  "AR" is not ok.   My first thought was "Anti Reflection".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know that I should put lenses between the display and the reflective glass but how would that work? What type of lenses do I need so that I achieve either a virtual image at +30 cm far or an infinite focal point? Wouldn't it be blurry and small vibrations will result in big vibrations on the projected image?

Comment: This can get complicated.  The basic thing to realize is that rays of light from distant objects are practically parallel when they get to your eyes.  Your optical system wants to do that:  make the rays of light coming from your display be parallel.  That way both your display and distant objects will focus on your retina.  This can be easier said than done.  The size of your display matters, the space allowable for optics matters.  Weight matters.   Depending on your specific situation you may end up needing a large, fast, impractical lens system, one having distortion and aberrations.

Comment: Hmm, got it, thanks. So it's hard and probably expensive. I thought there's some type of lenses that can "straighten up" and make rays parallel? Where can I start to even attempt to make such an optical collimated system?

Comment: fresnel lenses, and you will have a big problem because you have a fixed screen to eye distance with fixed lenses, and the objective of this headset seems to to be augmented reality. This would mean that your virtual image will have to be "projected" at a fixed distance from the user, i.e. 0.5m, but then things get "blurry" if you try to combine real world and headset image. The technology is probably out there and probably many people have worked on augmented reality sets that have some sort of active system to compensate for everything.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Thanks. I need the projected image to have an infinite focal point, therefore the world behind and the projected image will appear as one and the user will not have to refocus between the two. Any ideas on how I can get started, any articles or tutorials, anything?

Comment: I mean, most AR headsets most likely have collimation because it'd have been weird if you had to refocus between the overlay of holograms and the world behind lol

Comment: It's all good talking but I have no idea where to start or what to try/do

Comment: @JoséAndrade I have a fresnel sheet here with a diopter of 3 (it focuses when it's 30 cm above the ground) but I don't know what to do with it. Do you know how I can get started, what to do...? Other companies have done it and I'm sure their devices have collimated rays coming into the eyes, but I don't know how to do it. I'm lost on the details.

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean about "weird to refocus between hologram and world". I mean, I am typing on my keyboard and I am focused at about 0.5m. The hologram, if collimated, will be the same as a tower 20km away. I would have to shift focus regardless. That's why I was saying that you need to project the image at about arm's length. Or that or the only things you project and interact with are >4 m away.

Comment: @JoséAndrade By "having to refocus" I mean that if the projected image is 0.5m away from your eyes and a chair is 20m away, you'd have to choose which one to look properly (you can't both at the same time). And in devices such as Hololens, if you had to project a rabbit over that chair 20m away, you'd need a collimated projected image because if you got closer to the chair or away... the projected image needs to be collimated (i.e at infinite focal point). Maybe I'm wrong, I'm still new to this but this is what my intuition tells me. If I'm wrong, please correct me :-)

Comment: @JoséAndrade Hello?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been around. I believe they might collimate the projected light, but your argument is invalid, because you will always have to focus to infinity to see objects sharp and so, if you focused on something on your hand, either your hand or the object are blurry if it is projected to infinity. What I mean to say is that either you have an adaptive focusing system or you always have to "refocus" your eyes. In other words, using your rabbit on chair, if get within 5m of the chair where the rabbit is, either the rabbit, or the chair are in focus, if the rabbit is collimated.